# Is there any automated metrics collector for my Java project?

Tags: java, maven-2, continuous-integration, metrics, code-metrics

I'm trying to collect software code metrics in my Java project on every cycle of continuous integration. I'm interested mostly in size-related metrics like number of classes, number of methods, function points, lines of code, etc. I would like to get a summary report with these metrics in some XML file. Later I will use it in project report, or somehow else.

Is there any free open-source tool which I can integrate with Maven for this purpose?

Comment: Function points? Good luck with automating that! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_point

Comment: Apparantly the software metrics community can compute function points from code metrics by so-called "backfiring", basically multiplying by a constant factor that empirically relates code metrics values to function points.  Check out Capers Jones book: Applied Software Measurement http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0071502440/ref=oss_product

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One good option is [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/).

Its primary purpose is to manage technical debt, so it does a lot of things you don't need, but it provides really good metrics.

You can integrate it with Hudson or whatever other continuous integration system you are using.

Comment: +1 Hudson supports Maven, which has a Sonar plugin. The makes it trivial to get Hudson to run a sonar analysis nightly.

Comment: Not just nightly, you can have it run on every commit.  That is how we use it and it works great.

Comment: Well, so does your Hudson server, your Maven repo, etc etc.. not a big deal.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [javancss-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/javancss-maven-plugin/).

> JavaNCSS is a source measurement suite for Java which produces quantity & complexity metrics for your java source code.
>
> This plugin provides the capability to run the JavaNCSS tool on your Maven 2 project sources and produce an html report. Optionally you can fail the build whenever one of the metrics goes beyond a fixed limit.

Comment: NCSS stands for "Non Commenting Source Statements". Took me a while to work out :)

Comment: JavaNCSS is an old tool that doesn't handle correctly the syntax introduced by Java 1.5. `Sonar` is a far better alternative, and since 1.9 it bundles its own *JavaNCSS-like* tool, called `Sonar Squid`.

Comment: @romaintaz Sonar is excellent but I'm not sure that you're right about JavaNCSS: [the homepage](http://www.kclee.de/clemens/java/javancss/) lists support for 1.5/generics syntax.

Comment: @matt_b Annotations and Generics are in fact **partially** supported. JavaNCSS does not handle nested classes. That's why I said that this tool is a not up to date. Have a look here: http://www.sonarsource.org/the_next_major_version_of_javancss_is_on_its_way/

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in [XRadar](http://xradar.sourceforge.net/) which provides similar functionality to Sonar.